# SQL - How to return a COUNT value in a result set for all values in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a simplified version of what I am doing, I have been given the following codes:

1. 'code1'
2. 'code2'
3. 'code3'

I have been asked to find out how many cases we have against each of those codes on our database.

These codes can all be found within the CaseGroup Table along with many other codes but I only need to know numbers for the above codes.

The current SQL I am using:

```
SELECT 
    cg.code_typ as [code type]
    ,COUNT(*) as [Total] -- 62637
FROM 
    CaseGroup cg
WHERE 
    cg.code_typ IN ('code1', 'code2', 'code3')
GROUP BY
    cg.code_typ
```

My issue is that where the COUNT for a code type is 0, that code type is skipped from the result set. I would like a result set that has all three codes listed even if the count is 0. So it would ideally look like this:

```
CodeType    | Num of cases
code1       | 1 
code2       | 0 (or blank)
code3       | 3
```

The current results I am receiving look like this:

```
CodeType    | Num of cases
code1       | 1 
code3       | 3
```

I have actually been given around 100 different code types, there are over 150 different code types in the table and over 1 million cases, which is why its quite frustrating when code types are being skipped from the result set.

I have tried adding the different codes to a Temp Table and then joining the Temp Table to the query but still can't seem to get the desired result.  I'm sure there is a simple solution to this and if anyone can provide it that would be much appreciated.

If there's any extra information I can provide or a better title for this question, please let me know :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: the word that you are missing is distinct

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `left join` -- after constructing a list of all codes you really want.

```
SELECT c.code_typ as [code type],
       COUNT(cg.code_typ) as [Total] -- 62637
FROM (SELECT 'code1' as code_typ UNION ALL
      SELECT 'code2' as code_typ UNION ALL
      SELECT 'code3' as code_typ
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     CaseGroup cg
     ON cg.code_typ = c.code_typ
GROUP BY c.code_typ;
```

This uses a `UNION ALL`, which not all databases support.  But something similar can be used in whatever database you are using.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a solution, I'll give that a try :)